# Implicit Messages Provider instance was not found in Play framework with scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using playframework with scala and i am trying to build form but getting following error

"An implicit MessagesProvider instance was not found.
Please see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#Passing-MessagesProvider-to-Form-Helpers"
here is my index.scala.html

```
@(customerForm:Form[Customer])

@import helper._

@main("welcome") {
    <h1>Customer Form</h1>
    @form(action=routes.Application.createCustomer()) {
        @inputText(customerForm("Credit Limit"))
        @inputText(customerForm("Customer Name"))
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    }
}
```

And this is my application controller code

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models.Customer
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

class Application extends Controller {

  def customerForm = Form(mapping("Customer Name" -> nonEmptyText,
    "Credit Limit" -> number)(Customer.apply)(Customer.unapply))

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index(customerForm))
  }

  def createCustomer = Action { implicit request =>
    customerForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.index(formWithErrors)),
      customer => Ok(s"Customer ${customer.name} created successfully"))
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation (the link that is in the error you mentionned) ? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#Passing-MessagesProvider-to-Form-Helpers

Answer (score 14):

The play framework forms handling has changed between version 2.5 and 2.6, in order to make thing works you have to change the declaration of your Application class as follow :

```
import javax.inject._
import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport

class Application @Inject()(val cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) with I18nSupport
```

and in your view add an implicit parametre as follow :

```
@(customerForm:Form[Customer])(implicit request: RequestHeader, messagesProvider: MessagesProvider)
```

If you dont need the RequestHeader in your view you may omit its declaration.

Please refer to the link in your error message for more information :
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#Passing-MessagesProvider-to-Form-Helpers

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and in my case, I forgot to make request implicit. I hope this answer helps if you change the code as Achraf answered but still have the error.

```
def foo() = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(html.index(form))
}
```